# No mouse-clicking on any panel buttons or windows. Menu and other applets can be reached only with keyboard keys

Tags: linux, linux-mint

On Linux Mint 21, after suspending and waking up, I cannot click on the Linux desktop menu or the taskbar or on chosen tabs in one of the Firefox windows or any open window like one of my open shells. I remember that this came up after putting the laptop on a docking station, but it could also have been triggered just from suspending and waking it up.

A short research hints at a kernel problem, see [can't click buttons or other control in cinnamon desktop](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=211319) from 2014.

The "Have you tried turning it off and on again" voice whispers on a low level since there should be a better way than to lose all of the open sessions. How to get the clicks back without a restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Have you tried turning it off and on again" voice is not that bad again. But instead of a full restart, just suspend and wake up.